# How to fetch certain parameter from Folder response in Box.Com API?

Tags: box-api

According Box.Com documentation, to retrieve Folder’s Items, we have to pass

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items
```

We will get response like this :

```
{
"total_count": 24,
"entries": [
    {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "192429928",
        "sequence_id": "1",
        "etag": "1",
        "name": "Stephen Curry Three Pointers"
    },
```

I want to fetch only "total_count". What the endpoint should look like?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is specify limit=0:

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=0